# Convert JSON string to dict using Python

Tags: python, json, string

I'm a little bit confused with JSON in Python.
To me, it seems like a dictionary, and for that reason
I'm trying to do that:

```
{
    "glossary":
    {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv":
        {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList":
            {
                "GlossEntry":
                {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef":
                    {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I do `print(dict(json))`, I get an error.

How can I transform this string into a structure and then call `json["title"]` to obtain `"example glossary"`?

Answer (score 849, accepted):

[`json.loads()`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads)

```
import json

d = json.loads(j)
print d['glossary']['title']
```

Comment: What is the difference between json.load and json.loads ?

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal: Exactly what it says [on the tin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal: The difference is that `.load()` parses a file object; `.loads()` parses a string / unicode object.

Comment: It bothers me that the author of this function did not write a wrapper function to perform a type check on the data being passed in to automatically choose the right function to call. I also do not like the vague nomenclature used. Here is what I wrote to combat this: 

`def read_json(json_data):
    if (type(json_data) == str):
        return json.loads(json_data)
    elif (str(type(json_data)) == "<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>"):
        return json.load(json_data)` 

I'm sure this can be improved, but now you can call `d = read_json(j)` on a json 'str' or 'file'.

Comment: @JacquesMathieu, Hi Jacques, thanx for your function, I did a minor improvement since I sometimes use dictionaries:

def read_json(json_data):
    if (type(json_data) == str): # For strings
        return json.loads(json_data)
    elif (str(type(json_data)) == "<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>"): #For files
        return json.load(json_data)
    elif (type(json_data) == dict): # For dictionaries
        return json.loads(json.dumps(json_data))

Comment: Any particular reason why you guys are doing this awkward string comparison instead of something like `isinstance(json_data, io.TexIOBase)`? There's tons of types that behave _like_ a file and I'm guessing it'd be useful to catch those as well.

Answer (score 118):

When I started using json, I was confused and unable to figure it out for some time, but finally I got what I wanted
Here is the simple solution

```
import json
m = {'id': 2, 'name': 'hussain'}
n = json.dumps(m)
o = json.loads(n)
print(o['id'], o['name'])
```

Comment: Why are you dumps(m) first?

Comment: I used it to demonstrate serialization and deserialization. Using `loads(..)` on `'{"id": 2, "name": "hussain"}'` should also be fine like the accepted answer.

Comment: dumps and loads works perfect for me, while the accepted answer isn't, thanks a lot @Hussain for saving me a `time`, FYI, I'm trying to `loads` from dynamic strings with utf-8 encoding...

Answer (score 25):

If you trust the data source, you can use `eval` to convert your string into a dictionary:

`eval(your_json_format_string)`

Example:

```
>>> x = "{'a' : 1, 'b' : True, 'c' : 'C'}"
>>> y = eval(x)

>>> print x
{'a' : 1, 'b' : True, 'c' : 'C'}
>>> print y
{'a': 1, 'c': 'C', 'b': True}

>>> print type(x), type(y)
<type 'str'> <type 'dict'>

>>> print y['a'], type(y['a'])
1 <type 'int'>

>>> print y['a'], type(y['b'])
1 <type 'bool'>

>>> print y['a'], type(y['c'])
1 <type 'str'>
```

Comment: The string in your example is not JSON.

Comment: True. It evals to a dictionary tho, which can easily be loaded/dumped as JSON (and of course you might need a custom json encoder function if your dictionary has none json values).

Comment: No. You should *never* evaluate input data as a code. This may be your little pet project that uses data you trust, but bad code can be reused and bad practices repeated in real projects, leaving a big security code.

Comment: And that's why my answer starts with "if you trust the data source"! But true, this is more of a hack, and definitely not the best practice.

Comment: You can totally trust the data source if it's your own. This is actually useful to convert a stringified JS object into a dic into a proper JSON string.

Comment: @NetworkMeister Sometimes, eval is not evil if and only if the string is hardcoded / self-generated / initiate for your own needs. Plus no one can manipulate the data

Answer (score 22):

use simplejson or cjson for speedups

```
import simplejson as json

json.loads(obj)

or 

cjson.decode(obj)
```