# Convert string to JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, urllib3

I'm trying to convert a string, generated from an http request with urllib3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    data = json.load(data)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 286, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

>>> import urllib3
>>> import json
>>> request = #urllib3.request(method, url, fields=parameters)
>>> data = request.data
```

Now... When trying the following, I get that error...

```
>>> json.load(data) # generates the error
>>> json.load(request.read()) # generates the error
```

Running `type(data)` and `type(data.read())` both return `<type 'str'>`

```
data = '{"subscriber":"0"}}\n'
```

Comment: Your JSON has an extra bracket. Is that intentional?

Comment: What do you mean "Convert string to JSON"? JSON _is_ a string format. You want to convert JSON to the appropriate native Python objects (in this case a dict mapping one string to another)? Or some non-JSON string into a JSON string, or something different?

Comment: `type(data.read())` shouldn't work if `data` is a string.

Comment: In fact, `type(data.read())` is _guaranteed_ to raise the exact same exception as `json.load(data)`. I think he meant `type(request.read())`, which will successfully return the `str` type.

Comment: The extra bracket was a typo. Sorry about that. The data.read() was a typo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to JSON using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`json.load` loads from a file-like object. You either want to use `json.loads`:

```
json.loads(data)
```

Or just use `json.load` on the request, which is a file-like object:

```
json.load(request)
```

Also, if you use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, you can just do:

```
import requests

json = requests.get(url).json()
```

Comment: Or, instead of turning `json.load(request.read())` into `json.loads(request.read())`, just call `json.load(request)`.

Comment: I am using the requests library, though it is currently commented out. Working on Google Apps Engine which wasn't allowing me to run it, and urlfetch was having issues on the same GET request. So, they support raw urllib3 and that's what I'm testing with. `json.loads(request.data)` is wokring, `json.load(request)` does not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ` json = requests.get(url).json()` did not work for me as well
my original line of code
`pageContent = requests.get(url,verify=False).json()`

Comment: Limitation: the data parameter a=has to be <= 1GB, otherwise it will fail