# how to generate json string

Tags: python, json

I am referring this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python#)

This is my code

```
my_dictionary={}
a=[]
for i in range(1,5)

    jsonstring = {id[i] : marks[i]}
    a.append(jsonstring)
my_dictionary=json.dumps(a)
print(my_dictionary)
```

This is the output

```
[{"123": [86, 0, 0, 96, 45.5]}]
```

I want the string such as

```
{"123": [86, 0, 0, 96, 45.5],"124": [89, 0, 90, 96, 87],....}
```

Comment: The whole JSON encoding-decoding is a red herring. It *achieves nothing*. It is busy-work for no gain. Why do it at all? Just append `jsonstring` (which is *not* a string but a dictionary) to your list.

Comment: is there any better way?

Comment: Yes, just append the dictionary to your list, *and encode the list*.

Comment: At least, I'm *assuming* you want `studentInfo` to be a list. Did you mean for it to be *one big dictionary* instead?

Comment: Can you please update your question with some sample input, and expected output? That'd avoid further speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Just encode the *end result*. You are building a Python dictionary, add all your keys to one dictionary and encode the final result. Encoding to JSON then decoding again doesn't really achieve anything here.

```
studentInfo = {}
for i in range(1,5)
    studentInfo[id[i]] = marks[i]

jsonstring = json.dumps(studentInfo)
```

Rather than use an index, you can use `zip()` to combine `id` entries with `marks` entries:

```
studentInfo = {}
for student_id, student_marks in zip(id, marks):
    studentInfo[student_id] = student_marks

jsonstring = json.dumps(studentInfo)
```

Better still, you can simply produce the whole dictionary from the `zip()` output directly:

```
studentInfo = dict(zip(id, marks))
jsonstring = json.dumps(studentInfo)
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry but append is not working its just overwriting the value is there any problem?

Comment: @BhavikJoshi: *not working* doesn't tell me anything. Overwriting *what*? `list.append()` just adds the result to the end of a list, so nothing will be overwritten. Please add sample input and expected output to your question, and we can then work to produce that output.

Comment: so the string is there but it has only one previously appended string not the whole list of string added.

Comment: @BhavikJoshi: Your updated question shows you want one dictionary with multiple keys. Updated my answer to show that. I'm still not clear as to what you mean by a whole list here.