# how to add keys to list and convert to json in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661863/convert-a-list-to-json-objects) for converting list of list to json. But Could not convert to proper json format.

My data is

```
    data= [['India',
          'India runs mentorship driven incubation.',
          '/7e9e130075d3bfcd9e0.png'],
         ['Capital',
          'develops high growth and market-defining India-centric Software and Services Big Data and Analytics and Consumer Mobile or Internet markets.',
          '/data/images/512bc5a2937.png']]

    titles = ['Country','description','logo']

    values = [e for g in grouper(3, data) for e in g]
keys = (titles[i%3] for i in xrange(len(values)))

objs = [dict(g) for g in grouper(3, list(izip(keys, values)))]
print(objs)
```

result:

```
[{'Country': ['India', 'India runs mentorship driven incubation.', '/7e9e130075d3bfcd9e0.png'], 'description': ['Capital', 'develops high growth and market-defining India-centric Software and Services Big Data and Analytics and Consumer Mobile or Internet markets.', '/data/images/512bc5a2937.png']}]
```

But expected result should be in this form.

```
[{'Country': 'India', 'description': 'India runs mentorship driven incubation.', 'logo': '/7e9e130075d3bfcd9e0.png'}]
```

What should be reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a one-line list comprehension. First, iterate through data, an for each piece of data (`entry`), `zip` it with `titles` to create an iterable of tuples that can be converted into a dictionary:

```
data= [['India',
      'India runs mentorship driven incubation.',
      '/7e9e130075d3bfcd9e0.png'],
     ['Capital',
      'develops high growth and market-defining India-centric Software and Services Big Data and Analytics and Consumer Mobile or Internet markets.',
      '/data/images/512bc5a2937.png']]

titles = ['Country','description','logo']

result = [dict(zip(titles, entry)) for entry in data]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'Country': 'India',
  'description': 'India runs mentorship driven incubation.',
  'logo': '/7e9e130075d3bfcd9e0.png'},
 {'Country': 'Capital',
  'description': 'develops high growth and market-defining India-centric Software and Services Big Data and Analytics and Consumer Mobile or Internet markets.',
  'logo': '/data/images/512bc5a2937.png'}]
```