# convert string to json or list in python

Tags: python, json

i have this string `[['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9']]`

so I test all the ways to find out how to convert it to a list or a JSON format in python

when i try to convert it using `json.loads()`

it shows error

```
items = '[['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9']]'
item = json.loads(items)
```

and the error is

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: And please post the code you have tried.

Comment: 'Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)'

Comment: JSON requires double quotes around strings, not single quotes.

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()`

Comment: i edited the post with more details

Comment: Your `item` assignment has invalid syntax. If the string has single quotes inside it, either use double quotes around it or escape the single quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a list to json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661863/convert-a-list-to-json-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not JSON, it's Python syntax. Use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it.

```
import ast

items = "[['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9']]"
result = ast.literal_eval(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting wrong, this works:

```
>>> import json
>>> items = '[["18", "9"], ["18", "9"], ["18", "9"], ["18", "9"], ["18", "9"], ["18", "9"]]'
>>> item = json.loads(items)
>>> print(item)
[['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9'], ['18', '9']]
```