# What is the easiest way to create a python list from a string that is in JSON format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string

```
s = '[ 1 , 2 , 3]'
```

how to create a list from s?

Comment: Searching for [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) in the documentation wasn't easy enough?

Comment: print eval(s) would work in this example

Comment: @kezzos **please** avoid suggesting such a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all. I have read the doc link from @Yann Vernier. This is what I was looking for.


    s = '[1,3,4]'
    j = json.JSONDecoder()
    l =j.decode(s)

Comment: The answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python is not the answer of this question. I just find that the correct answer should be json.JSONDecoder().decode( '[1,2,3]' ). But I cannot click the answer now.

Comment: @palazzotrain, how is `json.loads` not the answer?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, my bad, json.loads does actually work. I thought you always need the field name in the string for loads function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `json` module:

```
import json
s = '[1, 2, 3]'
json_as_list = json.loads(s)
```