# How to load from Json?

Tags: python-3.x, api, urllib, restful-url

I'am trying to get the information from the web api with Python 3 but it gives me an error. That's my code:

```
import json, urllib.request, requests

def findLocation():
"""returns latlng location value in the form of a list."""

    send_url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'
    r = requests.get(send_url)
    j = json.loads(r.text)
    lat = j['latitude']
    lon = j['longitude']
    return lat, lon

location = findLocation()
print(findLocation()[0])
print(findLocation()[1])

def readJsonUrl(url):
"""reads the Json returned by the google api and converts it into a format 
that can be used in python."""
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data_bytes = page.read()
    data_str = data_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    page.close()

    return data_str
search =readJsonUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=indian+restaurantsin+Coventry&location=52.4066,-1.5122&key=AIzaSyCI8n1sI4CDRnsYo3hB_oH1trfxbt2IEaw")

print(search['website'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google api.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(search['website'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With updated lines now give another error. 
       Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "google api.py", line 35, in <module>
             print(search['result'])
       KeyError: 'result'

Answer (score 1):

The function you are using `readJsonUrl()` returns a string not JSON. Therefore, when you try `search['website']` it fails because the indices on a string can only be integers.
Try parsing the string value to a JSON object. To do this you can try the accepted answer here [Convert string to JSON using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

**data_str** is string ( not dict format ) You should convert **data_str** to dict! just add this line to your code : convert_to_dict = json.loads(data_str). then return convert_to_dict ... and done.

**Try this :**

```
import json, urllib.request, requests

def findLocation():

    send_url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'
    r = requests.get(send_url)
    j = json.loads(r.text)
    lat = j['latitude']
    lon = j['longitude']
    return lat, lon

location = findLocation()
print(findLocation()[0])
print(findLocation()[1])

def readJsonUrl(url):

    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data_bytes = page.read()
    data_str = data_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    page.close()

    convert_to_dict = json.loads(data_str)  # new line

    return convert_to_dict  # updated


search = readJsonUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=indian+restaurantsin+Coventry&location=52.4066,-1.5122&key=AIzaSyCI8n1sI4CDRnsYo3hB_oH1trfxbt2IEaw")
print(search['your_key']) # now you can call your keys
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for for the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` is because your `readJsonUrl` function is returning **str** object instead of **dict** object. Using the [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.loads) function can help you transfer the **str** object to **dict** object.

You can try something like the following:

```
def readJsonUrl(url):
    with (urllib.request.urlopen(url)) as page:
        raw = page.read().decode("utf-8")
    json_data = json.loads(raw)
    return json_data

search =readJsonUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=indian+restaurantsin+Coventry&location=52.4066,-1.5122&key=AIzaSyCI8n1sI4CDRnsYo3hB_oH1trfxbt2IEaw")

print(search['results'])
```

Hope it helps.