# How to parse JSON Array of objects in python

Tags: python, json

I received the following `JSON` Array from the `POST` response of an `HTTP` request:

```
[{
    "username": "username_1",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "roles": "system_admin system_user",
    "locale": "en",
    "delete_at": 0,
    "update_at": 1511335509393,
    "create_at": 1511335500662,
    "auth_service": "",
    "email": "userid_1@provider_1.com",
    "auth_data": "",
    "position": "",
    "nickname": "",
    "id": "short-string-of-random-characters-1"
}, {
  ...
}
<more such objects>..]
```

Given that `typeof(response)` gives me `requests.models.Response`, how can I parse it in `Python`?

Comment: You need to use the `json` module.

Comment: Is it an array or a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to JSON using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python) if not, then it's an array which means its already parsed as json, so I'm not sure what you're asking in that case

Comment: you might want to **mask personal information** such as *email*, *phone* etc from your *snippets* before posting on *public forums*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). More specifically the 'Decoding JSON:' section.

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get()  # api call

users = json.loads(response.text)
for user in users:
    print(user['id'])
```

Comment: Its not required for you to import json, Its simple python dict and use for loop without loading to json.

Comment: @prashantthakre How can you loop over the `dict` without first json decoding the string?

Answer (score 5):

You can try like below to get the values from json response:

```
import json

content=[{
    "username": "admin",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "roles": "system_admin system_user",
    "locale": "en",
    "delete_at": 0,
    "update_at": 1511335509393,
    "create_at": 1511335500662,
    "auth_service": "",
    "email": "adminuser@cognizant.com",
    "auth_data": "",
    "position": "",
    "nickname": "",
    "id": "pbjds5wmsp8cxr993nmc6ozodh"
}, {
    "username": "chatops",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "roles": "system_user",
    "locale": "en",
    "delete_at": 0,
    "update_at": 1511335743479,
    "create_at": 1511335743393,
    "auth_service": "",
    "email": "chatops@cognizant.com",
    "auth_data": "",
    "position": "",
    "nickname": "",
    "id": "akxdddp5p7fjirxq7whhntq1nr"
}]

for item in content:
    print("Name: {}\nEmail: {}\nID: {}\n".format(item['username'],item['email'],item['id']))
```

Output:

```
Name: admin
Email: adminuser@cognizant.com
ID: pbjds5wmsp8cxr993nmc6ozodh

Name: chatops
Email: chatops@cognizant.com
ID: akxdddp5p7fjirxq7whhntq1nr
```

Comment: please consider **masking personal information** such as *email* from *snippets* in your answer. See [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48189684/revisions) of question for more details

Answer (score 0):

use python 3 and import urlib

```
import urllib.request
import json
url = link of the server 
#Taking response and request  from url

r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
#reading and decoding the data
data = json.loads(r.read().decode(r.info().get_param('charset') or 'utf-8'))


for json_inner_array in data:
        for json_data in json_inner_array:
                    print("id: "+json_data["id"])
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems what you are looking for is the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module. with it you can use this to parse a string into json format:

```
import json
output=json.loads(myJsonString)
```