# Python Write a JSON temporary file from a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, temporary-files

I'm working on a python(3.6) project in which I need to write a JSON file from a Python dictionary.

Here's my dictionary:

```
{'deployment_name': 'sec_deployment', 'credentials': {'type': 'type1', 'project_id': 'id_001',}, 'project_name': 'Brain', 'project_id': 'brain-183103', 'cluster_name': 'numpy', 'zone_region': 'europe-west1-d', 'services': 'Single', 'configuration': '', 'routing': ''}
```

And I need to write `credentials` key to a JSON file.

Here's how I have tried:

```
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
saved_umask = os.umask(0o077)
path = os.path.join(tempdir)
cred_data = data['credentials']
with open(path + '/cred.json', 'a') as cred:
    cred.write(cred_data)
credentials = prepare_credentials(path + '/cred.json')
print(credentials)
os.umask(saved_umask)
shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
```

It's not writing a JSON formatted file, then generated file is as:

```
{
  'type': 'type1',
  'project_id': 'id_001',
}
```

it comes with single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to JSON using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python)

Comment: It’s not a duplicate, please!

Comment: Don't write the `dict` directly, write it with the `json` module so it gets properly encoded, i.e. `json.dump(cred_data, cred)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `json` module

**Ex:**

```
import json
with open(path + '/cred.json', 'a') as cred:
    json.dump(cred_data, cred)
```

Answer (score 19):

Actually this should be with the more Python 3 native method.

```py
import json,tempfile
config = {"A":[1,2], "B":"Super"}
tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+")
json.dump(config, tfile)
tfile.flush()
print(tfile.name)
```

To break this down:

- We load `tempfile`, and ensure that there's a name with `NamedTemporaryFile`
- We dump the dictionary as a `json` file
- We ensure it has been written to via `flush()`
- Finally we can grab the name to check it out

Note that we can keep the file for longer with `delete=False` when calling the `NamedTemporaryFile`