# Using json loads produces 'ascii codec can't encode characters' error in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

It feels like a a very basic question and I've already read through the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) and answers, that [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12455202/3298637) my code should be working. This may really be a duplicate and I missed something, please, drop a link as I've already spent a couple of hours on this and it feels silly. Thank you in advance.

Python 3.6 code:

```
import json
print( json.loads( '{"text": \"\\u0444\\u044b\\u0432\\u0430\"}' ) )
```

Produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 28, in <module>
    print( json.loads( '{"txt": \"\\u0444\\u044b\\u0432\\u0430\"}' ) )
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I had an impression that I can do

```
jsn = json.dumps( my_dict )
# and later call
json.loads( jsn )
```

And I will get back my original dict, but this doesn't work for unicode characters.

Can I convert a string containing unicode characters back to python dict with json.loads ? 
Please, provide a minimum working code for my example.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Does simply assigning the value, without printing it work?

Comment: The error comes from the `print`, not the `json.loads` anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not your code but your encoding settings of `stdout`.

The reason is the same as the following code:

```
import json
print(str(json.loads( '{"text": \"\\u0444\\u044b\\u0432\\u0430\"}' )).encode('ascii'))
```

`print` use `stdout` for default output, so your encoding settings of `stdout` is not "utf-8".
To check the encoding settings, type following code

```
import sys; print(sys.stdout)
```

you will get something like this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='' mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
```

the content of encoding is not `utf-8`; to change that, reopen `stdout` with `utf-8` encoding.

```
import sys
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding="UTF-8")
```

now the `print` should work.

but the deeper solution for this problem is to correct the environment settings of your system.

I have a solution for linux.
type `locale -a` in your terminal, the language settings of your current system will be listed, let we choose a "utf-8" encoded language.

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 # for english user
```

or

```
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 # 给中文用户
```

you may need to add it into `.bashrc` to make sure it always effective.

Comment: Originally, I was looking for a place, where json file encoding issue happens in my code, so I thought I could quickly print some variables, and that's where it led me astray.  Basically I was expecting this error, but from json library. And it came, but from print xD Your answer was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: setting sys.stdout with "TextIOWrapper" works like a charm! Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `sys.stdout` stream encoding, not with `json.loads()` - your code snippet works ok for me (using python 3.6.6 and a properly configured env). FWIW you could have found out by yourself by splitting the `print()` from the `json.loads()`.

TL;DR: check your OS doc for how to properly set the stdout encoding.