# Get value from json - API

Tags: python, json, api, bitmex

So I have an API conection established in python, everything is alright.
My question is how to get to the value of 'avgEntryPrice'?

```
[{'account': 231584,'simpleCost': 0.0, 'simpleValue': 0.0, 'avgEntryPrice': 0.0, ...}]
```

this is returned by:

```
client.Position.Position_get(filter=json.dumps({'symbol': 'XBTUSD'})).result()
```

and here is swagger.json for API https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors/blob/master/swagger.json?source=post_page---------------------------

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `let a = json.dumps(...)` + `a[0]['avgEntryPrice']`?

Answer (score 1):

```
positions = json.loads(result)  # result is an array so you will either loop over it or select first item

avg_entry_price = positions[0]['avgEntryPrice']  # first record solution
```

or

```
for position in positions:  # iterative solution
    print(position['avgEntryPrice'])
```

More answers and details [convert string to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python)