# How to convert following string to JSON in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

How can i convert the below string to JSON using python?

```
str1 = "{'a':'1', 'b':'2'}"
```

Comment: That string _is_ JSON. Do you mean how to parse that JSON into a Python dictionary?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read about [ask] and try doing a minimal searching effort by yourself. Hint: it's [in the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON string to dict using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-json-string-to-dict-using-python)

Comment: This string is not JSON. It uses single-quotes around the keys and values.

Comment: `str1 = str1.replace("'", '"')` then use the solution in the link.

Comment: That would work for this simple string, there could be other characters that would make this non-JSON, like a trailing comma. Better to use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the string to a dict.

Answer (score 2):

The `json` library in `python` has a function `loads` which enables you to convert a string (in JSON format) into a JSON. Following code for your reference:

```py
import json

str1 = '{"a":"1", "b":"2"}'
data = json.loads(str1)

print(data)
```

***Note***: You have to use `'` for enclosing the string, whereas `"` for the objects and its values.

Answer (score 0):

The string in OP's question is not JSON because the keys and values are enclosed by single-quotes. The function `ast.literal_eval` can be used to parse this string into a Python dictionary.

```
import ast
str1 = "{'a':'1', 'b':'2'}"
d = ast.literal_eval(str1)
d["a"]  # output is "1"
```

Other answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540688/5666087 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540879/5666087 were able to use the `json` library because they changed `str1` from `"{'a':'1', 'b':'2'}"` to `'{"a":"1", "b":"2"}'`. The former is invalid JSON, whereas the latter is valid JSON.

Answer (score -2):

```
import json

str1 = '{"a":"1", "b":"2"}'

jsonData = json.loads(str1)

print(jsonData["a"])
```

Reference : [LINK](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: "ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)" - better to test your code before posting. Also, the reference documentation is https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Hi @tyb9900! You had an good effort to contribute the answer. But, the string for JSON should be enclosed in `'` and not in `"`. Hope, that will help you improve your answer.