# Convert txt content into JSON using Python

Tags: python

I have the text data which has the format as shown below. How can I convert it into a JSON using python?

```
{"CRW_CODE":"CREW81","CRW_LASTSAVED":"2020-03-17 10:49:49.0","CRW_DESC":"Crew 37"}
{"CRW_CODE":"CREW82","CRW_LASTSAVED":"2020-03-17 10:49:53.0","CRW_DESC":"Crew 37"}
```

Comment: Did you try this previous SO answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-string-to-json-using-python

Answer (score 0):

you can use json module

```
import json
json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input....This code doesn't works if we have multiple tags like below :{
  "CRW_CODE": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX",
  "CRW_LASTSAVED": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR",
  "CRW_DESC": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"
} 
{
  "CRW_CODE": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX",
  "CRW_LASTSAVED": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR",
  "CRW_DESC": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"
}