# how to decoding JSON file in python and get specific key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
import requests
r = requests.get('test.com')
x=r.json()
print(x)
```

output is

```
{"test1":858,"test1":154343,"test":106091}
```

but x's type is `str`, how to get `key,value` from x ? i want to get only 858

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON string to dict using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-json-string-to-dict-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('test.com')
x = r.json()

print(json.loads(x)['test1'])
```

Output:

```
858
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json` function turns the response to a Python `dict` essentially, so you can use the `keys()` function or enum unpacking to get the keys and from there obtain the values.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that help you:D

```py
for k in x:
    print(x[k])
```