# Not able to access objects in json file using python

Tags: python, json

```
[
    {
        "label": "table",
        "ocr_text": "table",
        "score": 0,
        "xmin": 4,
        "xmax": 349,
        "ymin": 20,
        "ymax": 450,
        "cells": [
            {
                "id": "bcb82571-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 1,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 20,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 56,
                "score": 0.95537096,
                "text": "Company\nName:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82572-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 1,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 20,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 56,
                "score": 0.9363235,
                "text": "Calibrus Inc. (CALB) - United States",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82573-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 2,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 56,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 127,
                "score": 0.9946152,
                "text": "Company Profile:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82574-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 2,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 56,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 127,
                "score": 0.97803277,
                "text": "Calibrus, Inc. is a technology based\nCo. It has two business units that\nleverage the technology capabilities.\nThrough its Hosted Business Soluti",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82575-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 3,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 127,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 144,
                "score": 0.9714132,
                "text": "Chairman:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82576-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 3,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 127,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 144,
                "score": 0.9650206,
                "text": "Common",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82577-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 4,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 144,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 196,
                "score": 0.9955621,
                "text": "Mailing Address:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82578-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 4,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 144,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 197,
                "score": 0.9852098,
                "text": "Papago Spectrum, 1225 West\nWashington Street Suite 213, Tempe, AZ\n85281",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82579-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 5,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 196,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 216,
                "score": 0.9943174,
                "text": "Website:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8257a-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 5,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 196,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 216,
                "score": 0.9855827,
                "text": "www.caiibrus.com",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8257b-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 6,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 216,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 232,
                "score": 0.985591,
                "text": "Nation:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8257c-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 6,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 216,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 233,
                "score": 0.9716967,
                "text": "CHF",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8257d-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 7,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 232,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 251,
                "score": 0.99128944,
                "text": "Classification:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8257e-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 7,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 232,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 251,
                "score": 0.98732376,
                "text": "Раper",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8257f-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 8,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 251,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 269,
                "score": 0.99421144,
                "text": "Sub-Classification:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82580-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 8,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 251,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 269,
                "score": 0.9886955,
                "text": "Printing & Writing Paper",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82581-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 9,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 269,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 287,
                "score": 0.98516166,
                "text": "Recorder:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82582-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 9,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 269,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 287,
                "score": 0.98368365,
                "text": "OTC",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82583-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 10,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 287,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 305,
                "score": 0.99582994,
                "text": "PEG:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82584-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 10,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 287,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 305,
                "score": 0.9912583,
                "text": "CALB",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82585-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 11,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 305,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 323,
                "score": 0.9875233,
                "text": "P. E. Ratio:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82586-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 11,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 305,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 323,
                "score": 0.98438346,
                "text": "4,245,144 (Year Ending Jan2010).",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82587-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 12,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 322,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 341,
                "score": 0.99576724,
                "text": "Sedol:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82588-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 12,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 323,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 341,
                "score": 0.9900464,
                "text": "",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82589-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 13,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 341,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 358,
                "score": 0.9853235,
                "text": "Currency Traded In:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8258a-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 13,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 341,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 359,
                "score": 0.9750129,
                "text": "ZAR",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8258b-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 14,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 358,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 378,
                "score": 0.99585706,
                "text": "Listing Date:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8258c-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 14,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 358,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 378,
                "score": 0.9904988,
                "text": "23-05-2004",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8258d-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 15,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 378,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 394,
                "score": 0.9812952,
                "text": "No. Of Employees:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8258e-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 15,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 378,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 394,
                "score": 0.9752758,
                "text": "130/EUA",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb8258f-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 16,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 394,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 414,
                "score": 0.9942204,
                "text": "Market Capital:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82590-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 16,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 394,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 414,
                "score": 0.9909375,
                "text": "|мс3,057,570",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82591-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 17,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 414,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 431,
                "score": 0.99172026,
                "text": "Outstanding Shares:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82592-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 17,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 414,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 431,
                "score": 0.98513913,
                "text": "os6,794,600",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82593-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 18,
                "col": 1,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 4,
                "ymin": 431,
                "xmax": 127,
                "ymax": 450,
                "score": 0.96575403,
                "text": "Issued Shares:",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "bcb82594-1529-11ec-ac53-674c43174016",
                "row": 18,
                "col": 2,
                "row_span": 1,
                "col_span": 1,
                "label": "",
                "xmin": 127,
                "ymin": 431,
                "xmax": 349,
                "ymax": 450,
                "score": 0.96669304,
                "text": "IS3,009,501",
                "status": "",
                "row_label": ""
            }
        ],
        "type": "table"
    }
]
```

Not able to access data in json file.  Can anyone tell me  how to access data there I need the  content in **text** field.  I am doing a data entry job and want to convert data in image(table) to  text. Using nano nets I got this json file but now I cannot access the given  data in json file. Can anyone help solve this problem and tell how to access the text field using any foreign key.

Comment: Did you parse the json ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON string to dict using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-json-string-to-dict-using-python)

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the json python library as I did below. In data, you need the first element as your data is in a list.

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

cells = data[0]['cells']

for cell in cells:
    print(cell['text'])
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 16413: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: That might have something to do with how the text is saved. By copy-pasting the text into a file of my own it worked.