# Extract course and image_50x50 from a txt file using re method in Python

Tags: python, python-re

I have the following information in the txt file:

```
        "id":12,
     }
  ],

     {
        "id":1254578,

           {
           }
        ]
```

I tried splitting `item`: from the `unit`: using

```
course_id = re.search(' "id":(.*)')
```

Comment: You data is in JSON format, so you should first load the data using the json library.
Then you will have a Python Dictionary that will enable you to select any Data item.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528099/convert-json-string-to-dict-using-python>

Comment: I've used Jason formatter on the attached pic, but how do I access the "id": information? I tried splitting but no luck

Comment: which `id`? There are 2 in `items`

Comment: The first one with the course. However, I'd love to know how to extract the second one too, probably in a separate list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best regex but they work. Used `re.S` for dot all.

```
import re

text = ''
with open('my file.txt', 'r') as fd:
    text += fd.read()

# first id
m1 = re.search(r'type.+?"id":(\d+)', text, re.S)
print(m1.group(1))

# second id
m2 = re.search(r'_class.+?"id":(\d+)', text, re.S)
print(m2.group(1))
```

Comment: But how do I put data in triple quotes? It's a raw.txt file and I'm not allowed to edit it. I simply used Jason formater to get the above one-line sample code. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Tech ah sorry! I forgot that the text come from a file, I edit the answer

Comment: You're a legend Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use regex on the string

Just use python's json package to turn your `data` variable into a `dict`

Something like this

```
import json

course_data = json.loads(data)
course_id = course_data["unit"]["items"]["id"]
```

Comment: Thank you, but on my exercise, its asked not to use jason unfortunately. Either re or str